# I am trying to make a code that shows how many letters are in a string and im getting an error

Tags: c, for-loop, error-handling

the error:

error: relational comparison result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison]

```
for (int i = 0; (length = strlen(text)); i < length; i++)

                                         ~~^~~~~~~~
```

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; (length = strlen(text)); i < length; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
        letters++;
    }
printf("Letters: %i\n", letters);
return letters;
}
```

Comment: Im still new to coding, sorry

Comment: You should put `int length = strlen(text);` on the line before the loop. Then you have a simple loop: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`

Comment: The `for` header can only have 3 sections, you have 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 sections in the `for` loop header: initialization, repeat condition, and update. You have 4 sections. It thinks your initialization of `length` is the condition, and the comparison `i < length` is the update (`i++` is ignored since it's in an extra section).

If you want to initialize two variables, you can do them both in the initialization section, separated by comma.

```
for (int i = 0, length = strlen(text)); i < length; i++)
```

You can also just write `i < strlen(text)` as the condition, without setting a variable. As long as the loop doesn't modify `text`, most compilers will realize that the length doesn't change, so they'll optimize this to call `strlen()` just once.

Or you can use the condition `text[i] != '\0'` to stop when you reach the end, instead of getting the length first.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar noted, your `for()` statement has too many 'sections'. AND you've missed a curly brace marking the end of the `for()` code block... (Missing, too, is the start of the function... One can only guess...)

Even easier is this:

```
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) // This does what strlen() does without a function call
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    } // brace was missing..

    printf("Letters: %i\n", letters);

    return letters;
}
```

Curly braces can sometimes be clutter, and especially when indentation is *off* can lead to bugs.
This code can be made more *streamlined* leaving out unnecessary braces...

```
for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
        letters++;
```

And, the test again '\0' is often omitted, too...

```
for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++)
    if (isalpha(text[i]))
        letters++;
```

And, sometimes incrementing an index variable can be 'buried' into the last use of that variable

```
for (int i = 0; text[i]; )
    if (isalpha(text[ i++ ]))
        letters++;
```

And, then, C's guarantee of 0 and 1 (false and true) resulting from conditionals can be used to eliminate a slow, branching conditional...

```
for (int i = 0; text[i]; )
    letters += isalpha(text[ i++ ]);
```

The beauty of the C language.